# Parsing JSON, not sure on how and when to use iterators (Android Platform)

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, java-me

I have this JSON to parse

```
{"files_informations": {
                         "row":{"value":"artist1"},
                         "row":{"value":"artist2"}
                       }
}
```

I would like to know how can I get the first value **artist1** and then the second one **artist2**

This is what I am doing :

```
JSONObject myObject = jObject.getJSONObject("files_informations");
JSONObject rowObject = myObject.getJSONObject("row");
Iterator<JSONObject> rowIt = rowObject.keys();

while (rowIt.hasNext()) {
     JSONObject tmp = rowIt.next();             
     Log.e("", tmp.getString("value"));
}
```

I got java.lang.classCastException for this `JSONObject tmp = rowIt.next();`

**So there are my two questions** :

- Do I need to use iterators in this
  case ?
- How do one should use them ?

**Edit :**

Should the JSON looks like this ?

```
{"files_informations": [
                         "row":{"value":"artist2"},
                         "row":{"value":"artist1"}
                       ]
}
```

Comment: Your JSON may have a problem: your files_information key has two values with the key "row", and the second will actually overwrite the first when parsed. You should use an array for files_information.

Comment: Thank for your comment. I edited my post. Do you think the JSON should look like the one I posted ?

Comment: Your edited version is no valid json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rowIt.next()` is "row" `String` in this case.

Refactor your JSON to this:

```
{"files_informations":
  [ {"value":"artist2"},
    {"value":"artist1"} ] }
```

Or even this:

```
{ "files_informations": [ "artist2", "artist1" ] }
```

and then use:

```
JSONArray artistsArr = myObject.getJSONArray("files_informations");
for (int i = 0; i < artistsArr.size(); i++) {
     // first case
     Log.d(TAG, artistsArr.get(i).getString("value"));
     // Second case
     Log.d(TAG, artistsArr.getString(i));
}
```

Iterators are not supported in JSONArrays, however you can convert them to plain Java arrays/lists if you really need it.